# cp command prompts on overwrite even with -f

Tags: centos, bash, copy

I am trying to copy all newer jpgs from one folder to another using the following command

```
cp -u --force /home/oldfolder/*.jpg /home/newfolder/
```

and I get the following promt:

```
cp: overwrite `/home/newfolder/4095-181.jpg'?
```

The '-u' I know is working fine as is it only prompting me on the newer files, but i dont want to get the prompt i just want it to overwrite them. I have tried --force and -f

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Maybe your cp command is an alias? Try:

```
\cp -uf file folder/
```

Answer (score 18):

```
yes | cp <whatever else>
```

Comment: Cheers, that worked, so i didn't have to enter yes everytime but I still got the promt

Answer (score 9):

Type "type cp" to see where it points, or if it is aliased.

Comment: Had the same problem. Entering `type cp` revealed that `cp` was an alias for `cp -i`, and obviously `-i` (interactive) takes precedence over `-f` (force).

Answer (score 2):

Use full path to **cp** , it will override the alias

```
/usr/bin/cp -u --force /home/oldfolder/*.jpg /home/newfolder/
```